# Visa for Child born in the UK to parents on Tier 2 (General) Visa

Tags: uk-visa

I came to the UK on Tier 2(General) Visa on 26 April 2014. My wife and Daughter came along with me on Tier 2 (Dependant) Visa. Initial visa was valid until 31 January 2016. In December 2015, I have applied for a 3 year extension for all of us and got extension until 14 Feb 2019. I qualify for my ILR on  1st May 2019 which is 75 days away from my Tier 2 visa expiry date. So I am now planning to apply for an extension to my Tier 2 Visa.

We had a baby born in the UK in Feb 2017. As I was not intending to travel out of the UK with the baby, I had not applied for a Tier 2 (Dependant) Visa for the baby so far. Now that I am applying for an extension to my Visa, Do I need to apply for a visa for the baby as well? Is it legal not to apply for visa for the baby?

As I am planning on applying for ILR in May 2019, I want to find out if I can get away without having a tier-2 visa for the baby?

Thanks.

Comment: Per the linked question, no, you don't need to get a visa for your baby until you plan to travel outside the UK. You can indeed just wait until you apply for ILR, and submit an application for your baby at the same time.